# number of non-empty args passed to a macro

Tags: m4

In GNU M4, I've been trying to write a function that determines how many non-empty (args that don't equal `` `' ``) passed to it.

It's supposed to be callable like so:

```
ne_nargs(0, `1', `')
# 1

ne_nargs(0, `')
# 0

ne_nargs(0, `1')
# 1
```

Note that the first argument should always be `0`.

Here's the code that I've got so far:

```
define(`ne_nargs', `ifelse(`$#', `1`, $1,
   `ifelse(`$2', `', `pushdef(`$2', $1)ne_nargs(shift($@))',
     `pushdef(`$2', incr($1))ne_nargs(shift($@))')')')
```

And here's the pseudo-code for it:

```c
if (number_of_args == 1); then
  return first_arg; // which is `0` by default.
else if (second_arg == ''); then
  second_arg = first_arg;
  return ne_nargs(shift(all_args));
else
  second_arg = (++first_arg);
  return ne_nargs(shift(all_args));
```

---

```
ne_nargs(`0', `', `1', `i', `', `l')

# what I get
m4:test.m4:8: empty string treated as 0 in builtin `incr'
m4:test.m4:8: empty string treated as 0 in builtin `incr'
1

# what I expect
3
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in the definition of `ne_nargs`, and after trying a few different ways of abstracting parts of the macro, I'm about ready to give up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should try to overwrite `$@`; you can see from the warnings that overwriting $2 definitely isn't affecting `$@`. The [join example](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4//manual/m4-1.4.13/html_node/Shift.html) in the docs instead shifts out the second argument with:

```
`$0(`$1', shift(shift($@)))'
```

So the following works:

```
define(`ne_nargs', `ifelse(`$#', `2', `ifelse(`$2', `', `$1', incr(`$1'))',
  `ifelse(`$2', `', `$0(`$1', shift(shift($@)))',
    `$0(incr($1), shift(shift($@)))')')')
ne_nargs(`0', `', `1', `i', `', `l')
```

(I don't know a good way to cleanup the recursive call so the 2 argument call doesn't have to be independently checked, so that may be something to improve on if you are concerned about DRYness.)